# Python 3 absolute import does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a folder with two files: test.py and csv.py .  In test.py I have

```
import csv
```

This imports my csv.py file instead of importing the built-in csv module.

Why? I thought that absolute imports were default in Python 3?

How do I force Python to load the built-in csv module?

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

does not help.  Neither does

```
csv = __import__('csv', level=0)
```

which, according to the docs, should "only perform absolute imports".

Renaming csv.py is not an acceptable solution.  Also I'd rather not use the "from module import something" syntax (not that it helps in this case).

(Using Python 3.4.0 on Linux Mint 17.1)

Comment: `absolute_import` is already enabled by default as of 3.0 - see the table at the bottom of [the `__future__` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/__future__.html).

Comment: I thought so too.  So any idea why it doesn't seem to be working for me?

Comment: "How do I force Python to load the built-in csv module?"

Most preferably, don't shadow built-in names.

Comment: That is not an acceptable solution for me.  I don't intend to keep track of the built-in module names in python.

Comment: Also, aren't absolute imports supposed to solve this exact problem?

Comment: That's like saying 'i don't intend to track reserved words'. Just namespace your modules with a prefix, either in-name or with a directory as suggested the @MartijinPieters answer. That's the whole point of namespaces.

Comment: No it's not.  There are few reserved words, and their number doesn't grow nearly as fast as the number of packages.  (I haven't looked at stats, this is just a guess.)  Also, I suspect (though I haven't tried it) that non-built-in modules installed with pip or by my linux distribution can also be shadowed, so the list of reserved names can change by adding a new dependency to my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a top-level `csv` module, which lives on the `.` path, so it is found before the built-in module. This is how absolute imports *work*.

Move your modules into a package if you expected `csv` to be 'local'. Move your modules into a directory with your package name, and add a `__init__.py` file (it can be empty). Your `csv` module is then namespaced as `yourpackage.csv` and won't be considered as a top-level module.

Comment: I added an empty \_\_init__.py file.  Importing .csv doesn't work.  Neither does importing foldername.csv, where foldername is the name of the folder containing these files.  Where does "yourpackage" come from?

Comment: @uhuygiuhlk: did you create a new directory? A directory with an `__init__.py` file in it forms a package, but that top-level directory sits on your path, not the modules inside of the package. If you have a script to run this code keep that *outside* of your directory, and import from the package. This is how for example the [`urllib` packages](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) are organised; you import `urllib.request` for example, not `request`.

Comment: @uhuygiuhlk: the script part is important, the directory the script lives in is automatically added to your path, but you *do not* want the package directory to be added to your path, only the parent directory. So if you have `/home/username/python/foo` as your package, then you want `/home/username/python` to be on your path so you can import `foo` and `foo.csv`, etc. Put any scripts in `/home/username/python`.